# Loading image in jqGrid column

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jqgrid

I have a situation where I have button as one of the column in jqGrid. When user click the button it does some processing in the database. Once the process is complete the grid is updated using the latest data from the database. Grid is completely read-only. Can anyone suggest me, how can I show ajax loading image in exactly same place the button that was clicked, while process is running?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

So, the html which gets generated when this Loading... pops up is

```
<div id="load_list" class="loading ui-state-default ui-state-active">Loading...</div>
```

where the id "load_list" will be constructed from the prefix "load_" and the id of the table element.

//check for other html also, if its getting generated, you can hide that also. I guess this div gets loaded into a frame  having class name=jqgrid-overlay, check loading section in ui.jqgrid.css you will know what gets generated when that loading text appears, hide everything.

Now on the button click you can hide this div and do something like this.

$("buttonId").bind('click', function () {
    var spinner = $("").insertAfter(this);//have one ajax loading image.

```
jQuery.ajax({
    success: function (response) {
        // handle response

        spinner.remove();
    });
    });
});
```